# How can I display title and cover image of a playing audio in the Lock Screen

Tags: javascript, html, audio

How can I display audio information on the Lock Screen of mobile devices?
I'd like to display the following information:

- Artist name
- Album name
- Cover photo

I tried using `source`, `poster`, and `track` tags as follows:

```
<audio controls poster="cover-image.jpg" metadata>
  <source src="audio-file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

  <track kind="metadata" label="English" srclang="en" default>
    <source src="metadata.vtt" type="text/vtt">
  </track>
</audio>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

This is how it looks:

[image]

And this is my desired state:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set these in the mp3's meta data directly.

Artist name and album name you can edit in the mp3's meta data with VLC (Window > Media Information, "CMD + i" on a mac)

Unfortunately, you can't change the album cover there, I used ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i cover.jpg -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" output.mp3
```

The image is then "baked into" the mp3 file.